# Tizen install not finding vbs script engine

Tags: vbscript, tizen

I am trying to install Tizen SDK on Win10 laptop.

The first time I tried to install, it said I needed Java JDK, so I installed that.
The next and all subsequent times I try to install, I get the error that there is no script engine for .vbs.

I've tried a number of recommended fixes, each one indicating that there is now a vbs engine set.  But still Tizen installer doesn't see it.

I've restarted my computer.  Same result.

I downloaded the 32-bit version to see if that worked, and I got an error about a "wrong OS bit".

So I'm stumped.  Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Tizen SDK installation is not supported for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

SOLOVED !

" got exactly the same error message ("SDK programs are running under installed location...") on Windows 7x64 with Russian (or OTHER) localization.
I solved it after I changed the language for non-Unicode programs from Russian to English (USA) in Control Panel - Languages -  Administrative - Language for non-Unicode programs."

TEST CONFIRMED on Win10 x64

HERE https://samsung.tizenforum.com/index.php?topic=1230.msg5011#msg5011